# ZF2 jQuery datepickers not working in ajax dialogs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, zend-framework2

Some actions on my zend framework 2 web application open via a dialog. I use this method when processing an action that is called with ajax:

```
/**
 * Display content only on ajax call.
 * @param \Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $e
 */
public function onDispatch(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $e)
{
    $app = $e->getParam('application');
    $layout = $app->getMvcEvent()->getViewModel();
    if($app->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $controller = $e->getTarget();
        $controller->layout('application/ajax/ajax');
        $layout->setTerminal(true);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the datetime pickers of jquery do not seem to work. Because this HTML gets added dynamically to the page.

I think a solution might be to modify this `onDispatch` method so it also re-includes some of the JS-files. Or is there a better way? I just thought that adding the JS-files hard-coded into my `ajax.phtml` file would also work.

But again, i would like to know if there is a better approach exists, like reloading the js on the page or something.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, one way is to add the scripts to your ajax.phtml.

Something I did a while ago is to send the required scripts as a response header:

```
$requiredScripts = array(
    '/some/js/file.js',
    '/another/js/file.js'
);
$this->getResponse()->getHeaders()
    ->addHeaderLine('x-scripts: ' . json_encode($requiredScripts));
```

Then in your js:

```
// globally listen for the ajax-requests
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(res, status, xhr) { 
    var requiredScripts = xhr.getResponseHeader("x-scripts");
    if (requiredScripts) {
        jQuery.each(requiredScripts, function(index, scriptSrc) {
            jQuery.getScript(scriptSrc);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Turn out that it wasn't needed to reload the JS-files on the ajax.phtml view. I simply called the initDatePickers() function again in the onready event of the jquery ($.get) ajax call. Now the datepickers work fine in the dialog itself.

Comment: If the problem is that your events don't trigger because the elements are created after you registered the events, you can use `$(document).on('click', '.date-picker', function(evt) { ... });` instead of `$('.date-picker').click(function(evt) { ... });`.